# Static pagination in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to set up pagination in Next JS, but I'm not able to figure out how to achieve this through getStaticProps. I am able to do this through getServerSideProps with the query parameter, but this is not accessible through getStaticProps. The data is coming from local Strapi backend.

Here is the example of getServerSideProps (which works):

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query: { page = 1 } }) {
const { API_URL } = process.env;

const start = +page === 1 ? 0 : (+page - 1) * 3;
const numberOfCakesRes = await fetch(`${API_URL}/cakes/count`);
const numberofCakes = await numberOfCakesRes.json();

const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/cakes?_limit=3&_start=${start}`);
const data = await res.json();

return {
    props: {
        cakes: data,
        page: +page,
        numberofCakes,
    },
};
```

}

Then I just hook up the buttons to the router to go back and forth.

```
onClick={() => router.push(`/?page=${page - 1}`)}
```

I need access to something similar to the query parameter in getServerSideProps.
Is what I'm asking for achievable statically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Because `getStaticProps` runs at build time, it does not receive data
> that’s only available during request time, *such as query parameters*
> or HTTP headers as it generates static HTML.
> [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#only-runs-at-build-time)

One thing you can do is instead of putting the page no in the query, put it as a route parameter, i.e users will visit `/3` instead of `/?page=3`.

To achieve it, you need to create a `[page].js` in the `pages` directory and export a `getStaticPaths` function:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  // query Strapi to calculate the total page number
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { page: '1' } },
      { params: { page: '2' } },
      { params: { page: '3' } }
    ],
    fallback: true or false // See the "fallback" section in docs
  };
}
```

And also a `getStaticProps` function:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const { page } = context.params;
  // fetch page data 
  return {
    props: { ... }, 
  }
}
```

Learn more about `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` in Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).

Comment: are there cases where one could have advantage more than the other?

Comment: but what do we do if we don't know how many pages will be at build time? If there are tonnes of pages surely we shouldn't enumerate our paths

Comment: @x86-64 then you can use [incremental static generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#incremental-static-regeneration)

Comment: @x86-64 as @shivam-jha mentioned you can either use ISG and build these pages as they are accessed (with the preferred `fallback` setting), or if you REALLY want to pre-build these statically, inside of `getStaticPaths` you can dynamically fetch your content and determine how many pages you would need with pagination limit and current number of entries, then return built paths for all the necessary/possible pages (`/cakes/1`, `/cakes/2`, `/cakes/3`, etc.), however if your content would require dozens/hundreds of pages, you probably wouldn't want this over a simple ISR with `blocking` option.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the query parameters for your pagination (sth like `/foo?page=2`) and SSG together, there is a workaround I just came up with.

You can use Next JS [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) and [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) features.

First, use the `/foo/[page].js` file format and statically generate all the pages, as [hangindev.com has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629949/9333798).

Then, in the `next.config.js` file, you have to export two functions:
`async redirects()` and `async rewrites()`.

```js
module.exports = {
  ....
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/foo/1",
        destination: "/foo?page=1",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/foo/2",
        destination: "/foo?page=2",
        permanent: true,
      },
      {
        source: "/foo/3",
        destination: "/foo?page=3",
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },

  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/foo",
        has: [{ type: "query", key: "page", value: "1" }],
        destination: "/foo/1",
      },
      {
        source: "/foo",
        has: [{ type: "query", key: "page", value: "2" }],
        destination: "/foo/2",
      },
      {
        source: "/foo",
        has: [{ type: "query", key: "page", value: "3" }],
        destination: "/foo/3",
      },
    ];
  },
  
};
```

The `redirects()` function, ensures that users can't see the pages in `/foo/2` format, because they get redirected to `/foo?page=2`. And the `rewrites()` function displays the content from `/foo/2` page for the `/foo?page=2` URL.

Comment: This works beautifully; however, this can be optimized slightly by using wildcard redirects/rewrites:
`{source: '/foo', has: [{ type: 'query', key: 'page' }], destination: '/foo/:page'}` and `{source: '/blog/:page', destination: '/blog?page=:page', permanent: true}`.  This way you only have to add it once, not for every page.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I wanted to show verbosely what is actually happening. Your code is actually cleaner.